# CSS animating down instead of up

Tags: javascript, html, css

The short is I have three `div` containers with a `border`.
Inside each is a `div` with a background color set to `100%` width and height.
The idea is that when I click them the water should empty out, top to bottom. 
I do this by switching the internal `div`'s height from `100%` to `0%` with transition.
However of course this just makes the water levitate up.
So I've been looking for most of the afternoon and haven't come up with anything.
I'm looking for the most simple way of just making it go backwards or to flip the y axis as it were, which on the face of it can't be that difficult, can it?

Anyway, here's a code pen, because jsfiddle want allow css animation, of what I'm Trying to do.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgYEKE

```js
function func1(buttonname) {
    var x = document.getElementById(buttonname).className;

    if (x = "full") {
        document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "empty";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "full";
    }
}
```

```css
.full {
    height: 100%;
    transition:height 2s;
 }

 .empty {
     height: 0%;
     transition: height 2s;
 }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
        <div id="glass1" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water1" class="full"  style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="glass2" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water2" class="full" style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="glass3" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water3" class="full" style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
        <button id="button1" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water1</button>
        <button id="button2" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water2</button>
        <button id="button3" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water3</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

On a side note I also believe I have correctly written the Javascript to switch between the empty and full classes but only seems to work one way, if you have any idea what I did wrong there it would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1.) In the `if` condition it has to be `x == "full"`  instead of  `x = "full"`

2.) In my snippet below I styled the "water" as an `absolute` positioned element with settings `top: 0px; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0` (no `height` setting) and animated/transitioned the `top` setting, so `bottom` stays at 0 all the time. Now the "water" empties from the top, and you also can "refill" it with another click from bottom to top. (I also moved the CSS from inline to external to make it easier to comprehend, BTW)

```js
function func1(buttonname) {
 var x = document.getElementById(buttonname).className;

 if ((x == "full")) {
  document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "empty";
 } else {
  document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "full";
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}
#glass1, #glass2, #glass3 {
 position: relative;
 height: 50px;
 width: 25px;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 margin: 3px;
}
.full {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 2s;
 background-color: aqua;
}
.empty {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 2s;
 background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
<div id="glass1">
<div id="water1" class="full" ></div>
</div>
<div id="glass2">
<div id="water2" class="full" ></div>
</div>
<div id="glass3">
<div id="water3" class="full"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
<button id="button1" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water2</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the most comprehensive answer and the animation is the more robust option too. The only downside being that it requires knowing the height of the container. Those looking for an alternative for when the height of the container is not known should look to the ScaleY option outlined in Aziz's post. However be aware that the scaleY solution has issues with switching classes before the transition has completed.

Comment: @SimonGreen After your comment, I edited my snippet once more: Instead of the px value for `top` (when empty) you can as well use `top: 100%`, so in fact you *don't* have to know the height of the container.

Answer (score 2):

Element height starts from top to bottom by design, you can use the `scaleY` transformation instead while declaring a `bottom transform-origin`.

**Demo**

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div div {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

div div:hover {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Aziz, this got me on the right track.
I appear to have gotten so focused on transforming the height that I didn't think to look for other ways to do it only how to do it backwards
once both classes were set to transform from bottom and scaley everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the glass elements a relative position and the water elements an absolute position from the bottom

```
.glass { 
    position: relative;
}

.water {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

And apply this classes to your elements like this:

```
<div class="glass" id="glass1" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
    <div class="water" id="water1" class="full"  style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
    </div>
```

Also there is an error in the click function,

```
if (x = "full"){
```

is assigning the variable, should use == to compare. I guess this is a demo typo

Comment: Thanks Sergio,
this is my bad, I'm hardly ever use javascript so was just trying to apply other programming logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your if is wrong, you are setting always `full` state. Change to comparison it works perfectly.

```js
function func1(buttonname) {
    var x = document.getElementById(buttonname).className;

    if (x == "full") {
        document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "empty";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(buttonname).className = "full";
    }
}
```

```css
.full {
    height: 100%;
    transition:height 2s;
 }

 .empty {
     height: 0%;
     transition: height 2s;
 }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
        <div id="glass1" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water1" class="full"  style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="glass2" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water2" class="full" style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="glass3" style="height:50px;width:25px;border:2px solid blue;margin: 3px;">
            <div id="water3" class="full" style="width:100%;background-color:aqua;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:center;">
        <button id="button1" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water1</button>
        <button id="button2" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water2</button>
        <button id="button3" onclick="func1(this.innerHTML)">water3</button>
    </div>
</body>
```